# How to correctly use Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler to launch an Activity in all cases?

Tags: android-activity, android

I would like to override the default `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` in my whole application in order to launch a new error-displaying `Activity` whenever something goes wrong.

I was able to write some code and get it half-working, but there's a problem that I just can't figure out how to fix. The class that extends `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` can launch a new `Activity` if an uncaught exception occurs any time after `onCreate()` in one of the other Activities of the application. However, if an uncaught exception occurs in `onCreate()` or before the UI is drawn on the screen, my error-displaying `Activity` does not launch and my app just kind-of hangs there.

I can reverse this behavior by saving the default `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` and passing the uncaught `Throwable` to it in `uncaughtException()`. This causes exceptions to be handled in `onCreate()` of other Activities, but any exceptions past `onCreate()` simply launch the default "Unfortunately, Application has stopped." dialog and my error-displaying `Activity` does not launch.

... on to the code!

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler;
    private ExceptionRouter exceptionRouter = null;

    public MyApplication() {
        defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        exceptionRouter = new ExceptionRouter();
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(exceptionRouter);
    }

    public class ExceptionRouter implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
            launchErrorActivity(throwable);

            // Uncommenting the following line makes what I want to do work in other Activities' onCreate() but not after
            // Leaving the line commented out makes what I want to do work after other Activities' onCreate() but not in it
            // defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(thread, throwable);
        }

        private void launchErrorActivity(Throwable throwable) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            Intent errorIntent = new Intent(context, ErrorActivity.class);
            errorIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putSerializable("throwable", throwable);
            errorIntent.putExtras(extras);

            context.startActivity(errorIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

I have verified that the line `context.StartActivity(errorIntent);` is reached in all cases.

What can I do to fix my issue?

Answer (score 0):

One time I need show dialog after exception and I show the dialog like show below. Maybe this code help you.

```
public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(fragmentActivity);
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();

                builder.setTitle(title);
                builder.create();
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setPositiveButton(positiveButtonText,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                                //some action
                            }
                        });
                builder.setMessage(message);
                builder.show();

                Looper.loop();
            }
        }.start();
}
```

Comment: I would like to launch an Activity, not display a dialog. However, if you don't mind, where do you set the uncaught exception handler in your code?

Comment: I know that you want start activity but I don't have enough time to test code with activity. I seted handler in onCreate method in Application class.

Comment: It seems that your builder relies on a FragmentActivity for the context. How do you pass this in?

Comment: My application class contains field Fragment activity

Comment: Do your Activities call a setter in your Application class to make a reference to themselves? I would like to try to avoid this, but if that's the only solution, I may have to go with it.

Comment: Yes, I call setter in Activity.